# Prove that the polynomial $f_m(x) = x^3 − 3x + m$ never has two roots in [0, 1], for all m in R

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I understand that the function never has two roots because it is only crosses the x-axis once due to it being a cubic, but I don't know how to prove it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E3+-+3x+%2B+1 Many cubics have three distinct real roots.  I believe the task is to show in this problem it never has exactly two.

Do you know the fundamental theorem of algebra?

Comment: for $m < 0,$ Descartes' rule of sign tells you that $f$ has only positive root so $f$ cannot have two roots in $[0,1].$ for $m > 0,$ use the fact $df/dx > 0$ on $(0,1).$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** By taking a derivative, show that for any $m \in \mathbb R$, we have that $f_m(x)$ is strictly decreasing on the interval $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

As a double root would be a root of $f_m'$ (why?), you could differentiate and see that it can't have a root at $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the derivative $f_{m}'(x) = 3x^{2} - 3$ which has two roots at $x = \pm 1$. This means that $f_{m}(x)$ has only two local extrema at $x = -1, 1$, and its values there are $f_{m}(-1) = 2 + m$ and $f_{m}(1) = -2 + m$. If $|m| \leq 2$, then by the intermediate value theorem $f_{m}(x)$ will have a root on the interval $[-1,1]$.

Now suppose that $f_{m}(x)$ has two roots inside of $[0,1]$. By Rolle's Theorem, there must exist a point $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f_{m}'(c) = 0$. However, this is impossible since we showed above that the only critical points of $f_{m}$ are at $x=\pm 1$.